# Prettifying a conversion from m(metres) to feet(') and inches ('')

Tags: php, unit-conversion

I'm creating table for defining an individual's [BMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index). The chart (as yet) doesn't take input (because I want to make the thing work stand-alone, first), but it does show (on parallel axes) the height in both metres and feet/inches.

In order to do this I'm defining the metres' start point and range and then converting the defined metres variables into feet/inches, to do which I've come up with (please don't *laugh*...) the following:

```
<?php
        $m; // height in m

        $hInInches = ($m*3.2808399)*12;

        $hInImp = explode(".",$hInInches);

        $hInFt = $hInImp[0];

        $hInInches = substr(12*$hInImp[1],0,2);
?>
```

I was wondering if anyone has any prettier, more economical, more accurate means by which this could be done, since this is being run inside of a for () loop to generate `x` numbers of rows (defined elswhere), and I'd like (if possible) to reduce the load...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach, in psuedo-code:

```
inches_per_meter = 39.3700787
inches_total = round(meters * inches_per_meter)  /* round to integer */
feet = inches_total / 12  /* assumes division truncates result; if not use floor() */
inches = inches_total % 12 /* modulus */
```

You could pull out the `12` to a constant as well...

Comment: Thanks derobert, the concept of using a constant hadn't occurred 'til I read these answers...can you tell I'm noob at php? O.o thanks again! =)

Answer (score 1):

To me you should avoid the string manipulation functions as derobert already stated.
In php the code should be similar to the following one:

```
<?php
   $m=2; // height in m
    $hInFeet= $m*3.2808399;
$hFeet=(int)$hInFeet; // truncate the float to an integer
    $hInches=round(($hInFeet-$hFeet)*12); 
?>
```

Just two multiply and a subtraction (plus a function call to round) are quite economic, and the code is quite readable too.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you consider [this](http://cvs.moodle.org/moodle/lib/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier/UnitConverter.php?view=co) prettier; however, I'd argue that an [ajax/javascript](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&ei=DNkOSsPEEobKtgfnyYT1Bw&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=unit+conversion+javascript&spell=1) solution might be idea. As the user enters the value, the results update.

```
with regards to your code
* define M_TO_FEET, FEET_TO_INCH constants.
* define 2 equations feet_to_metres(value_to_convert) and metres_to_feet(value_to_convert)
* write the conversion code in each and let it return the result

and then you can create a simple if statement:
* If user inputs metres, then metres_to_feet(value_entered_by_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php echo metersToFeetInches(3); //call function    ?>

     <?php
        function metersToFeetInches($meters, $echo = true)
        {
            $m = $meters;
            $valInFeet = $m*3.2808399;
            $valFeet = (int)$valInFeet;
            $valInches = round(($valInFeet-$valFeet)*12);
            $data = $valFeet."&prime;".$valInches."&Prime;";
            if($echo == true)
            {
                return $data;
            } else {
                return $data;
            }
        }
        ?>
```

output : 9′10″